# How to create a Cronjob in spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, kubernetes-cronjob

I created a cronJob using kubectl. I would like to manage this job using spinnaker but i cant find my created job in spinnaker.

I created the file running "kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/job/cronjob.yaml"

This cronjob looks like this: https://k8s.io/examples/application/job/cronjob.yaml

Comment: what do you mean you can't find it? try kubectl get cronjobs

Comment: sorry, i didnt mentioned that. I want to see tje job in spinnaker

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue open on Github and based on recent comment on [How do I deploy a CronJob? #2863](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2863#)

> ...
>   At this time, there is no support for showing CronJobs on the cluster screen, which is intended to focus more on "server-like" resources rather than jobs.
>   ...

As for deploying CronJobs in Spinnaker:

> ... was not possible prior to Spinnaker 1.8. It has been possible to deploy cron jobs since Spinnaker 1.8

Like @[Amityo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626280/amityo) mentioned you can show deployed CronJobs using `kubectl get cronjob`, and if you like to list jobs scheduled by this CronJob you can use `kubectl get jobs`.

This is really well explained in official Kubernetes Documentation [Running Automated Tasks with a CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).